# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa

Tried all possible solutions but can't resolve this error. The application is very basic. I have used MySQLDialect 8 as I use mysql version 8.0.22 but still the error persists. What shall be done to resolve this issue. This is the error  that I am getting

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-08 20:28:36.746 ERROR 7660 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.springrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>springrest</artifactId>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>springrest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>


            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8050

#database configuration:mysql

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sampledb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

#Hibernate config

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect="org.hibernate.dialect,MySQL8Dialect"
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

**Course.java**

```
@Entity

public class Course {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "<seq name in java in generator anno>")

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "<seq name in java in generator anno>", sequenceName = "<seq name in db>", allocationSize = 1)

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Course() {
        super();
    }

    public Course(int id, String title, String desc) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a typo and used "," instead of ".".

Try changing "org.hibernate.dialect,MySQL8Dialect" to "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" in your configuration file.

Check if your database URL is correct and if your database is up and running. Also check if your username and password are correct.

Comment: Changed "," to "." and checked the url, username and password but the same error is coming.